# IsAuthorized = False, Facebook C# SDK 4.2.1

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have a problem after upgrading to version 4.2.1. when i try to do an ajax post, im still getting false in authorizer.IsAuthorized()

Default.aspx:

```
    $('.WallPost').click(function(e){

        //get the form
        var f = $("#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>");
        //get the action attribute
        var action = 'http://www.domain.com/FacebookTestZone/Call/WallPost.aspx';
        //get the serialized data
        var serializedForm = f.serialize();
        $.post(action, serializedForm, 
            function(txt) { 
                alert(txt);
            }
        );            

    });
```

WallPost.aspx.cs:

```
fbApp = new FacebookApp(); 
authorizer = new CanvasAuthorizer(fbApp);

    if (authorizer.IsAuthorized())
    {
        Response.Write("IsAuthorized = True");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("IsAuthorized = False");
    }
```

Comment: previous version was ok when i set cookieSupport="true" in web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send the signed_request value with the ajax request. We no longer support cookies in iframe apps because it was a mess and unreliable. Do something like the following with your form post:

```
  $('.WallPost').click(function(e){

        //get the form
        var f = $("#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>");
        //get the action attribute
        var action = 'http://www.domain.com/FacebookTestZone/Call/WallPost.aspx?signed_request=<%=Request.Params["signed_request"] %>';
        //get the serialized data
        var serializedForm = f.serialize();
        $.post(action, serializedForm, 
            function(txt) { 
                alert(txt);
            }
        );            

    });
```

Comment: I'm good with the "cookies no longer supported" decision...but where exactly is that documented or described?  The release notes just say cookie support is now "automatic"

Comment: yeah i tought the cookie support is automatic.

Comment: Its not that they aren't supported, but they are only supported when used correctly. Cookies should never have been used in an iframe app. Cookies are only for Facebook Connect sites.

Comment: ok 1 more thing, if i use this solution, on safari it doesnt work. is there anyway to put the signed_request manually ?